# Where did the phrase "Give it some wellie" originate?

Tags: etymology, british-english

I've heard this a few times, and I would presume that it comes from Wellingtons, with the meaning of put some boot to it.

Is there an origin for this phrase?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_words_not_widely_used_in_the_United_States#W

Comment: Well, I never said the link was supposed to answer your question. I, for one, didn't know about the phrase so I put up a link for others like me to have a reference. That's it.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան - I grok.

Comment: Could it refer to the Duke of Wellington and his battles...?

Comment: Eeee... you chaps are giving this discussion a fair bit of wellie!

Answer (score 4):

You are all missing the point that Wellies were, and still are, worn on working farms and would indeed be used when driving a tractor. It's credible then that 'give it welly' would be shouted at someone driving a tractor, hauling a load or driving out of the mud and it necessary then to push hard on the accelerator in order to get out of the mud or shift the load. The phrase, in hiberno-english would have been originally used in a farming context or a building site for the same reason.

Comment: Did you just post supposition as fact without any actual evidence?

Comment: It's a phrase I would definitely use to mean something along the lines of "floor it".  e.g. (from http://www.northloop.co.uk/reports_oct%5B02%5D05.htm) "Just before the start of the long left-handers, Clare slipped into 4th gear and gave it some welly."
It's also used in football (soccer) parlance for giving a ball a really hard kick.
In both cases, I would assume (but as yet have no proof) that it comes from Wellington boots.

Comment: *Wellies* are what *wellington boots* are normally called, in the UK. They are not just worn on farms or with tractors. They are worn in all sorts of situations when people want to keep their feet and lower legs, clean and dry.

Answer (score 3):

OED has the definition...

> ***wellie/welly**: slang. A kick, acceleration. Also fig.*

...under the entry for *Abbrev. of **Wellington** [boot]*, but I must admit when I use the expression *"Give it some wellie!"* I've always assumed I'm referencing a derivative of...

> ***welt**
>
>    Verb: To beat, thrash.
>
>    Noun: A stroke with a lash or pliant stick; also, a heavy blow with the fist.*
>
> ["Let me **give it a welt** with my hammer"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20good%20welt%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22give%20it%20a%20welt%22&tbm=bks)
>    ["...give it a **good welt** from the back and it will come out"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20good%20welt%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22give%20it%20a%20good%20welt%22&tbm=bks)

So unless anyone can produce evidence of *"give it some boot"* being an earlier/alternative form, I'm sticking with my current thoughts on the matter.

---

EDIT: On the basis of *no evidence whatsoever*, I'm now more than willing to give credence to the possibility that the origin relates to [Welly Wanging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wellie_wanging), which could have either started or been gaining nationwide awareness around the late 60s / early 70s (the same time as the expression under consideration here). The art of successful welly-wanging is to impart as much acceleration to the boot as possible before flinging it.

There are also probably [phonosemantic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism) factors involved in the retention / spread of currency. Ordinarily, the *wang* in welly-wanging means "throw", but [here, for example](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give%20it%20a%20whang%20sometimes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) it's a *welt, whack, wallop, wham, whop*. Lots of *w-* words imply the application of force.

Comment: http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-giv2.htm There is this, but it is anecdotal.

Comment: Very interesting. My guess had been for *wellie* to mean *velocity*. Wellington boots look plausible.

Comment: @JohnP: It became commonplace during my childhood, at a time when I was also accustomed to hearing my parents threatening me with things like *"I'll give you such a welt!"* So the *hard blow* association seems natural to me. And I really can't see people talking about *giving someone a hard kicking* or *flooring the car accelerator pedal* in the context of wearing wellington boots. That sounds about as likely as *give it some high-heeled shoes* (not exactly the appropriate footwear for the occasion! :)

Comment: This expression isn't used in the U.S., as far as I know; but Nigel Rees, _A Word in Your Shell-like_ (2004) says that the phrase "to give something some welly" dates "from the 1970s, in British use." He writes: "'Wellies' is, of course, a common name for waterproof, rubber (Wellington) boots, so perhaps the image is that of  booted foot being applied to a spade in some digging task that requires a good deal of effort."

Comment: @Sven: I of course *am* a Brit, and the expression was gaining traction when I was a teenager. Nowadays, you might hear it used in all sorts of contexts (at a concert, encouraging a drummer or singer to "belt it out", say). But so far as I recall it was originally only used in respect of thrashing/revving a car or motorbike engine, which you probably wouldn't be doing in wellington boots. In the days before the [Green Welly Brigade](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Green%20Welly%20Brigade) *wellie=boot* was the language of children, not "desperately-trying-to-be-men" adolescents.

Comment: Thanks for the followup, FumbleFingers. Apropos of Nigel Rees, is he generally regarded as a well-informed commenter on UK slang and word usage? I ask because his books cover many, many expressions that I've never heard used over here in the U.S., so I have no independent sense of how reliable he is. I wouldn't want to bring his opinions up on EL&U if he's widely regarded as a charlatan in the geographical regions where he claims expertise. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sven: I'm not exactly a "scholar", but Nigel Rees certainly has my endorsement in general. And for all I know, everyone else except me thought (and continues to think) *giving it some wellie* somehow derives from *"Give it some wellington boot!"*. But I grew up thinking of it as a (new, "cool") derivative of *"Give it a welt/belt/thrashing!"*, and I can't change my past. For me personally, that's the reference I've always *intended*, regardless of whether it's been/being received as such by others.

Comment: In *Doctor Who*, (Ep: The Doctor's Wife) the Doctor says to Amy, "Right now I'm burning up TARDIS rooms to give us some welly. Goodbye, swimming pool. Goodbye, scullery. Sayonara, squash court seven." (He was trying to get more power out of his time machine.) One could deduce he was giving it a thrashing, but one can also say the good doctor was putting the pedal to the metal. He wouldn't have been bringing down a bruising on himself and Amy, would he?

Comment: @Susan: Oh, yes - there's no doubt the original (and still, *main*) sense is "increase power [to gain *speed*]". I just don't think it got started as an allusion to flooring a wellington-booted foot on the accelerator pedal. The kind of vehicles you'd be likely to be driving in wellies (tractors, fork-lift trucks on building sites, etc.) aren't exactly known for being "acceleratable"! :)

Comment: Ah, I understand better now, thanks. I must admit to a significant lack of understanding about BrE phrases/idioms. I do find them colorful, though.

Comment: @Susan: Actually, although I said in my answer "unless anyone can produce evidence [to the contrary] I'm sticking with [wellie=welt=forceful blow]", coming back to this one another possibility occurs to me. It's all really just idle speculation, but I'm gonna edit in my latest idea...

Answer (score 1):

*Give it some wellie* appear in several searches to mean *give it some gas* or, colloquially in AE, **put your foot into it** (put your foot down on the gas pedal), **step on it** (step on the gas pedal).

[Wiktionary UK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_it_some_welly) sums it up similarly:

> (UK) To increase fuel or power to an engine, as to a car by depressing the gas pedal.
>
> (UK) To apply great physical effort to (something).

[Here is a humorous blog](http://britwordoftheday.blogspot.com/2011/05/give-it-some-welly-heard-on-doctor-who.html) on the subject of the origin of *give it some welly*, which points to the site called [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-giv2.htm) (you have to search for yourself it you use the link in the link given by Simms, but I've linked directly to the page). World Wide Words suggests the phrase came about in the 1970's, either in the motor racing world, meaning *put your foot down on the accelerator pedal*, or in football, meaning *put some power into your kick*.

Comment: *Give it some gas* is part of American English, not British. So is the word *gas* when used to mean a fuel for motor vehicles, which is called *petrol* in the UK.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't focused on that point, but since you mention it it, Wiktionary UK uses the word "gas". Now I'm wondering who wrote that. I thought going over the the .co.uk domain would bring in some local knowledge and authenticity.